# Transformar em decimal no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Galera, tenho uma planilha em que o comprimento largura e altura estão assim: 0,07 (exemplo)

Preciso que fique assim: 7 (exemplo)

Como faço isso em todas as células de uma vez só?
Obrigado

Comment: Sua pergunta não parece estar bem formulada.. Seu título não parece corresponder ao que você deseja.. Explique melhor

Answer (score 1):

Selecione a coluna(A,B,C,D...) em questão, botão direito, largura da coluna e informe o tamanho desejado. Faça o mesmo selecionando a linha(1,2,3..) em questão, botão direito, altura da linha e informe a altura da linha desejada.

A seleção pode ser feita em uma ou mais colunas clicando e arrastando com o mouse.

Se quiser selecionar todas linhas e todas colunas da sua pasta de trabalho utilize o atalho Control + t  e irá selecionar tudo.

Utilizei o excel 2013 para fazer os testes.